# Terraform cloudwatch conflict with log types

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting the following error while running `terraform plan` command:

```
Error: aws_rds_cluster.my_rds_cluster: expected enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports.0 to be one of [audit error general slowquery], got postgresql
```

I am using terraform-aws-provider version 2.24. I am trying to use cloudwatch with RDS Aurora PostgreSQL.

```
aws rds modify-db-cluster \
    --db-cluster-identifier my-db-cluster \
    --cloudwatch-logs-export-configuration '{"EnableLogTypes":["postgresql", "upgrade"]}'
```

Comment: Can you show relevant TF code that results in the error?